# SQL Left join - Fixed value from Right table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 tables say A and B. As part of the existing process, it works something like this

```
Select A.a, B.b
from A left join B
on A.c=B.C
and B.b = 'xyz'
```

Now, due to a specific requirement, I need to have B.b = 'xyz' in the where clause. Something like this

```
Select A.a, B.b
from A left join B
on A.c=B.C
where B.b = 'xyz'
```

But as soon as I do this, It works as an inner join.

How shall I tweak my query such that I get the desired output using the where clause.

Comment: snowflake datawarehouse

Comment: `where B.b = 'xyz' or B.b IS NULL` should do it. Though I don't really follow your requirement to move the condition to the `where`

Comment: Yuo should explain what you are trying to do. Putting a condition in the `where` clause does turn the join to an `inner join`, there is nothing that can be done about that.

Comment: If you have `WHERE B.b = 'xyz'` then that requirement **must** be met, therefore yes, it implicitly turns into an `INNER JOIN`. Leave the clause `B.b = 'xyz'` in the `ON` and it'll remain a `LEFT JOIN`; which seems like what you want.

Comment: OK so the reason why I want it in where clause is B.b=xyz needs to be passed as a parameter in the view. I have a view with lots of Inner Join, Left join etc, This B.b will be passed as a parameter from SAP BO universe, So eventually it will call the view as select * from view where B.b = 'xyz'. It can be 'vuw' or 'abc' or 'xyz'. But from SAP BO, it will always be passed in where clause.

Comment: Views can't be parametrised. you can still, however, parametrise an `ON` clause. `ON B.b = @Parameter` is perfectly valid.

Comment: If SAP BO is **always** adding the `where B.b = 'xyz'` clause, then SAP BO is **forcing** an inner join. The problem lies in SAP BO. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: So can we do something at BO end so that it doesn't impact my left join?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot.  Well, you can if you use a subquery in the `from` clause:

```
select A.a, B.b
from A left join
     (select B.*
      from B
      where B.b = 'xyz'
     ) B
     on A.c = B.C;
```

You could also use a correlated subquery if only one row matches::

```
select A.a,
       (select B.b
        from B
        where A.c = B.C and B.b = 'xyz'
       ) B
from A;
```

Or, you could "union all" in the extra results:

```
select A.a, B.B
from A left join
     B
     on A.c = B.C
where B.b = 'xyz'
union all
select A.a, NULL
from A
where not exists (select 1 from B A.c = B.C and B.b = 'xyz')
```

It is tempting to write:

```
select A.a, B.b
from A left join
     B
     on A.c = B.C
where B.b = 'xyz' or B.b is null;
```

However, this is not the same logic.  Consider:

A

```
A    C
1    1
2    2
```

B

```
B     C
xyz   1
abc   1
abc   2
```

The left join version returns:

```
1    xyz
2    null
```

The `where` version returns:

```
1    xyz
```

The "2" row is filtered out because there is a match on another value.

Comment: The `where B.b = 'xyz' or B.b is null` works as I would expect. My assumption was that the OP would want to return records where b.b = 'xyz' *OR* all records that don't match the join condition. If you add a record like this in table A: (3,3) then the 'where B.b = 'xyz' or B.b is null' returns what I would expect?

Comment: @SimonD . . . I don't know what you expect.  My point is that the `WHERE` clause is an imperfect approximation of the `LEFT JOIN`. In particular, it can filter out rows, which the `LEFT JOIN` does not.

Comment: Congratulations Gordon !

Comment: @Vonc . . . You will be there soon enough.  Cheers.